# Adding a play/pause button on an animated gif without being taken to the URL of the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to do the following:

- add a CTA play/stop button (to be independently activated by the user) on an animated gif that programmatically already stops within 5 seconds;
- avoid to be taken to the URL of the image when clicking on the button, that means that action on the button are distinct from action on clicking on the image area.

I have initially made use of [Gifffer](https://github.com/krasimir/gifffer), a great library for automatically stops animated gifs, but it does not really fit with what I would like to do (it stops the images on loading), despite the fact that draws a very nice button and I am struggling to modify it to be able to achieve what I would like.

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2016/12/02/animated-gif/" rel="bookmark" title="Animated Gif"><img alt="source" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" height="249" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/source.gif" width="500"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have re-used the nice Gifffer features to create a play/stop button, as follows:

```
    var doc = document;
    var playButton = doc.createElement('div');
    playButton.setAttribute('class','Button');
    //nice settings from Gifffer
    var playSize = 60;
    playButton.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + playSize + 'px;height:' + playSize + 'px;border-radius:' + (playSize/2) + 'px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-' + (playSize/2) + 'px');
```

I have then tried to create jsfiddle by including the following code in a function:

```
    function createPlayButton(context, func){
    var doc = document;
    var playButton = doc.createElement('div');
    playButton.setAttribute('class','Button');
    //nice settings from Gifffer
    var playSize = 60;
    playButton.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + playSize + 'px;height:' +  playSize + 'px;border-radius:' + (playSize/2) + 
    'px;background:rgba(0,  0, 0,  0.5); position:absolute;
    top:50%;left:50%;margin:-' + (playSize/2) + 'px'); 
    playButton.onclick = func;
    context.appendChild(playButton);
}
```

which then, I believe, it can be called from within window.onload, as follows:

```
window.onload = function(){
    createPlayButton(document.body, function(){
        highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
        createPlayButton(this.parentNode, this.onclick);
    });
}
```

I am not even able to create the button, let alone prevent to be taken to the image URL when clicked. Can you help? Here is the jsfiddle, note that I have replaced the animated gif with a static image as in my scenario the image has been already "frozen":

https://jsfiddle.net/55dbv890/

Thank you,

Comment: If you paste your JavaScript into [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) you'll find there are a few apparent errors that are likely to preclude your JS running at all. Also if you don't try calling the function - in the linked demo - it definitely won't run.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant, thank you. Not a FE dev and I have just ventured into it. I have updated the jsfiddle, but cannot see any button, am I missing something fundamental here? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of playing/pausing a gif is to get a frame of the gif and use the static image as the *off* state of the button, and use the animated gif as the *on* state of button.

The following Snippet demonstrates the use of toggling classes to meet OP's objective. Details are commented in the source:

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>gifClick</title>
</head>

<body>


  <script>
    /*~~ gifClick(image, gif, location, width, height)
                | Creates a button with given gif as
                | background, when clicked, the gif will 
                | "seem to pause" when in fact it is just
                | swapped out with a static image.
                | All parameters are required, 
                | there are no defaults.
                */
     // image[string] = url of static image
     // gif[string] = url of gif
     // location[string] = CSS selector of element you
     // want to place button in. 
   
     // ex. "body" or ".frame" or "#main"
     // width[number] = number of px for width of button
     // height[number] = number of px for height of button

    function gifClick(image, gif, location, width, height) {
        // Create button
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        // Set image and gif urls as string values
        var imgStr = 'url(' + image + ')';
        var gifStr = 'url(' + gif + ')';
        // Reference location of where the button will go
        var L = document.querySelector(location);
        // Set the dimensions and style of button
        btn.style.width = width + 'px';
        btn.style.height = height + 'px';
        btn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
        btn.style.backgroundSize = 'contain';
        btn.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        btn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        // Call function setStyle() to create 
        // the .on and .off classes. 
        // setStyle() is a separate function.
        setStyle('.on {background-image:' + gifStr + ';}.off{background-image:' + imgStr + ';}');
        // Set initial state .on and append button
        setTimeout(function() {
          btn.classList.add('on'), L.appendChild(btn);
        }, 0);
        // When the button is clicked...
        btn.onclick = function() {
          //...if the button has class .on...
          if (btn.classList.contains('on')) {
            //...wait 1 second and...
            setTimeout(function() {
              //...change the state to .off...
              btn.classList.add('off');
              btn.classList.remove('on');
            }, 1000);
          }
          //...otherwise...
          else {
            //...change the state to .on
            setTimeout(function() {
              btn.classList.remove('off');
              btn.classList.add('on');
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
      }
      /*~~ setStyle(str)
      | Takes a given string, wraps it in <style> tags,  
      | then inserts this style block as the first 
      | child of the body.
      */

    function setStyle(str) {
        var string = '<style>' + str + '</style>';
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', string);
      }
      /* Usage */
    var png = 'http://imgh.us/gir_zim.png'
    var gif = 'http://imgh.us/gir_zim.gif'
    var loc = 'body';
    gifClick(png, gif, loc, 128, 128);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting approach, but my requirement is to have a play/stop button on the animated gif. I am working with Wordpress and clicking on animated gif as featured image will take me to the article, so I need to have a CTA button to be activated by the user. Clicking anywhere on the image, other than on the button, needs to take the user to the article.

Comment: The button is the image, adding a link could be added as well.

Comment: The button I am trying to add on top of the gif's frame (I already managed to stop the animated gif within 5 second) should play/stop the featured image on the Wordpress home. By default, featured images take to an article and that is fine, but this should not happen when clicking on the button. I had a good start with Gifffer(https://github.com/krasimir/gifffer), but the button was placed inside the <a href> and each time I click on the button I am taken to article, which is not what I want.

Comment: You want a separate button that pauses and plays a gif?

Comment: Yes and when I click on the WordPress feature image/animated gif still being taken to the article.

Comment: It sounds like you have a wordpress plugin that'll see an image and automatically includes a link to either a specified location or the location of image if it isn't specified.

Comment: Thanks for your input, my first goal would really be to be able to apply a CTA visible play/stop button on the frame on which the animated gif has been stopped. The removal of the <a href> is step 2.

Comment: To remove anchors from images `$('.wp-post-image').unwrap()` assuming jQuery is loaded on your page